# Python list of dictionaries representation

Tags: python

I have a python list of dictionaries.

```
 [{u'c_user': u'100001724251788'},
 {u'datr': u'AUojUqoBUYA2wj4j04GT5XvX'},
 {u'lu': u'RitwQJMNRJ8siUh_9eIj4SMw'},
 {u's': u'Aa7ebY1RvmeilCX8.BSI0od'},
 {u'xs': u'62%3AjNm_3ySkegf7cg%3A2%3A1378044445%3A10945'},
 {u'fr': u'0aU8cfDygWXo1ETQA.AWV9BQIzKARYURFpuxUdXLoXcl8.BSI0od.j_.FIj.AWXjyq2t'}
 ]
```

I want to convert it into this format.

```
<cookies>.facebook.com:c_user:121004739910369<cookies>.facebook.com:datr:37unUBLPm65_tx_Bw1abJlMs<cookies>.facebook.com:fr:0hxSSm1eLzrtkN4AA.AWUjxn2WujCDmYEexTPNUdlhpuw.BQp7wW.uk.AAA.AWUPRZl0<cookies>.facebook.com:lu:ggan5YObFPPgWGf_wt4INraQ<cookies>.facebook.com:s:Aa58EZ-VAVc8GtmK.BSH5bk<cookies>.facebook.com:xs:1%3AkqDOXnuUt-6jGg%3A0%3A1377801956%3A16993<cookies>
```

**Note**: The value of key are diff in this example.. But they will be same in actual implementation.

I am new to python. Sorry, if my question sounds stupid.

Comment: That kind of looks like XML, but the tags are all unclosed. Was that intentional?

Comment: Yes, its intentional. I am trying to plug my data to some old script which uses this format.

Comment: Those who downvoted. Care to comment for downvote?

Comment: Kind of silly that it's a list of dictionaries, when a single dictionary (or `OrderedDict` if ordering is important) would be just fine...

Comment: Any ideal way of doing this? I can hack togther piece using all sort of complex regex. But i am trying to find a cleaner way.

Comment: I think the difficulty is that it's not obvious how the one format maps to the other.  For example, why facebook.com?  How do I know to use that?

Comment: @MarkR.Wilkins , it will same for all data. In this example i used "facebook".

Comment: @user2737882: This problem doesn't appear to need regex at all. If you think it does, please elaborate.

Comment: Ok, then nneonneo has your answer.

Comment: There's no similarity between the values in the list and in the cookie string. That's weird

Comment: @eyquem: I just assumed he had one example of "correct" data and a separate example of "Python-generated" data.

Comment: @eyquem, There is no similarity between values. But keys are same. I have already put a note on question about it. "Value may vary in example, implementation will have same values"

Comment: @user2737882 You're right. I precise that I'm not one of the downvoters. On the contrary, I've just upvoted, now, because I find it's not fair to welcome a new user on SO with downvotes. And your question has nothing objectionable. By the way, see my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let `L` be your list. Then:

```
out = ['<cookies>.facebook.com:%s:%s' % (k,v) 
       for d in L for k,v in d.iteritems()]
print ''.join(out) + '<cookies>'
```

Comment: Thank you! loved the way you simplified it!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could find interest in knowing that if you have the possibility to define a dictionary

```
d = {u'c_user': u'100001724251788',
     u'datr': u'AUojUqoBUYA2wj4j04GT5XvX',
     u'lu': u'RitwQJMNRJ8siUh_9eIj4SMw',
     u's': u'Aa7ebY1RvmeilCX8.BSI0od',
     u'xs': u'62%3AjNm_3ySkegf7cg%3A2%3A1378044445%3A10945',
     u'fr': u'0aU8cfDygWXo1ETQA.AWV9BQIzKARYURFpuxUdXLoXcl8.BSI0od.j_.FIj.AWXjyq2t'}
```

instead of your list of dictionaries,
you will be able to write simply:

```
pat = (u'<cookies>.facebook.com:c_user:{c_user}'
       '<cookies>.facebook.com:datr:{datr}'
       '<cookies>.facebook.com:fr:{fr}'
       '<cookies>.facebook.com:lu:{lu}'
       '<cookies>.facebook.com:s:{s}'
       '<cookies>.facebook.com:xs:{xs}'
       '<cookies>')

print pat.format(**d)
```

to give the same result